# C++ library management

Tags: c++

Can anyone please this line, if y == totalBook-1 then print book not found.
This is a library management system and this code is for searching a book. I just dont get the y == totalBook-1 how does it work?

```
if(totalBook!=0){
        cout<<"Enter the book ID you want to search: ";
        cin>>id;
        for(int y=0; y<totalBook; y++){
            if(id==bookID[y]){
                cout<<"Book found!"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Book name: "<<bookName[y]<<endl;
                cout<<"Book author: "<<bookAuthor[y]<<endl;
                cout<<"Book ID: "<<bookID[y]<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                break;
            }if(y == totalBook-1){
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Book not found!"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
```

Heres the full code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char yesNo;
    string bookName[50];
    string bookAuthor[50];
    string bookID[50];
    int totalBook=0, choice; //for case 1
    string id; // for case 2 and 3
    int j; //case 2
    do{
    system("CLS");
    cout << "==========================" << endl;
    cout << "LIBRARY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM" << endl;
    cout << "==========================" << endl;
    cout << "[1] Add Books" << endl;
    cout << "[2] Delete Books" << endl;
    cout << "[3] Search Books" << endl;
    cout << "[4] View Book List" << endl;
    cout << "[5] Close Application" << endl;
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice){
    case 1: // add book
        if(totalBook<50){
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Enter book name: ";
        getline(cin, bookName[totalBook]);
        cout<<"Enter book author: ";
        getline(cin, bookAuthor[totalBook]);
        cout<<"Enter book ID: ";
        getline(cin, bookID[totalBook]);
        totalBook++;
        cout<<"Book succesfully added!"<<endl;
        }else{
            cout<<"Library is full!"<<endl;
        }
        break;
    case 2: //delete a book
        
        if(totalBook!=0){
        cout<<"Enter the book ID you want to delete: ";
        cin>>id;
        for(int y=0; y<totalBook; y++){
            if(id==bookID[y]){
                for(j=y; j<totalBook; j++)
                bookID[j]=bookID[j+1];
                bookName[j]=bookName[j+1];
                bookAuthor[j]=bookAuthor[j+1];
                totalBook--;
                cout<<"Book deleted succesfully"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                break;
            }else if(y == totalBook-1){
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Book not found!"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
            }}
        }else{
                cout<<"The library is empty!"<<endl;
            }
        break;
    case 3: // search book
        if(totalBook!=0){
        cout<<"Enter the book ID you want to search: ";
        cin>>id;
        for(int y=0; y<totalBook; y++){
            if(id==bookID[y]){
                cout<<"Book found!"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Book name: "<<bookName[y]<<endl;
                cout<<"Book author: "<<bookAuthor[y]<<endl;
                cout<<"Book ID: "<<bookID[y]<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                break;
            }if(y == totalBook-1){
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Book not found!"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                break;
            }}
        }else{
                cout<<"The library is empty!"<<endl;
            }
            break;
        
    case 4: // display all the books
        if(totalBook!=0){
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"===================="<<endl;
        cout<<"All Books Available"<<endl;
        cout<<"===================="<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        for(int y=0; y<totalBook; y++){
      
          cout<<"Book name: "<< bookName[y] << endl;
          cout<<"Book author: "<< bookAuthor[y] << endl;
          cout<<"Book ID: "<< bookID[y] << endl;
          cout<<endl;
      }  
        }else{
            cout<<"The library is empty!"<<endl;
        }break;
    case 5:
        cout<<"Thank You!";
        exit(0);


    }cout<<"Do you want to continue (Y/N): ";
    cin>>yesNo;
    }while (yesNo == 'y' || yesNo == 'Y');
        cout<<"Thank You!";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you need is unclear, and your code misses trailing brackets.

Comment: I just need to know how it works 
if(y == totalBook-1){
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Book not found!"<<endl;
                cout<<endl;

Comment: the y == totalBook-1

Comment: @nustifatru When `y == totalBook-1` then the program has checked every book and not found anything, so it prints 'not found'. I wouldn't code it like that but that how it works.

Comment: @nustifatru The rest of the code has bugs (at least two I've spotted very quickly). Where did you find the code? I wouldn't trust it, try writing your own code. You'll learn more that way.

Comment: @john it is mine. Its working perfectly for me. What bugs?

Comment: So you wrote the code but you don't understand it? Huh? Anyway one bug is that you are missing `{}` for the for loop when you delete a book  `for(j=y; j<totalBook; j++) bookID[j]=bookID[j+1]; bookName[j]=bookName[j+1]; bookAuthor[j]=bookAuthor[j+1];` should be `for(j=y; j<totalBook; j++) { bookID[j]=bookID[j+1]; bookName[j]=bookName[j+1]; bookAuthor[j]=bookAuthor[j+1]; }` Note the extra `{}`

Comment: i copy the y==totalBook-1 so I have backup, and it is working without {} in that line

Comment: @nustifatru Another bug is that you should do `totalBook--;` before the for loop that deletes the book not afterwards. The way you have it written you move a book that doesn't exist, and would overflow your array if you have 50 books

Comment: I recommend creating a `struct`/`class` containing the data belonging to a single book. This would make it possible to work with e.g. the algorithms library much simpler. Also you'd avoid having to mention the maximum book count 3 times. This would allow you to write the logic as `auto pos = std::find_if(books, books+totalBook, [&id](Book const& b) { return id == b.id; }); if (pos == (books+totalBook)) { cout<<"Book not found!\n"; } else { cout << "Book name: " << pos->name<<endl; ... }`

Comment: @nustifatru You are mistaken. Without the braces your for loop only copies the `bookID`. No doubt your teacher will point this out if you don't believe me.

Comment: @john like this?
 for(int y=0; y<totalBook; y++){
   if(id==bookID[y]){
    totalBook--;
    for(j=y; j<totalBook; j++){
    bookID[j]=bookID[j+1];
    bookName[j]=bookName[j+1];
    bookAuthor[j]=bookAuthor[j+1];
    }
    cout<<"Book deleted succesfully"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    break;
   }else if(y == totalBook-1){
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Book not found!"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
   }}

Comment: @nustifatru That looks better, but be advised that I'm only looking at the code. I could be getting things wrong. You still need to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the book is available in the system, the program will exit the for loop.
The last value that will be assigned to y will be `totalBook - 1` since `y < totalBook`. If at that point, book could not be found, the text `Book not found` will be printed.